# how to use .htaccess to redirect http to https for 3 domains cPanel

Tags: htaccess, redirects, https

I have 3 domains. 2 are Addon domains, 1 primary on my cPanel. I do not know if this is possible but from `.htaccess` how can I set this up:

- `example1.com` (Primary)
- `example2.com`
- `example3.com`

This is what I want to do:

- `example1.com` > HTTP to HTTPS
- `example2.com` > HTTP to HTTPS
- `example3.com` > HTTP to HTTPS

From the `.htaccess` on cPanel I tired doing this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://www.example1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://www.example2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://www.example3.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

it didn't work. Please help with solution.

Comment: Are all domains sharing the same directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect various http domains to certain https domain via htaccess](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84760/redirect-various-http-domains-to-certain-https-domain-via-htaccess)

Comment: Hi, they on separate folders, only the primary is in public_html

Comment: Also, note - Its only the primary that is actually doing the redirect properly. The addons are still sticking to the http

Answer (score 1):

cPanel is notoriously bad for managing redirects. (I didn't think you could create HTTP to HTTPS redirects using cPanel alone?)

> I do not know if this is possible...

Probably not from cPanel. But this is relatively straightforward in `.htaccess` (by directly editing the file itself). To be honest, if something of this nature is not possible in `.htaccess` then it's probably not something you should be doing in the first place.

If you simply want to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS on the same *hostname* then all you need is something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on the same host
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains the *hostname* from the request. eg. `example1.com`, `example2.com`, `www.example1.com`. Note that this alone does not canonicalise the www subdomain.

This is also a 302 (temporary) redirect (the same as simply specifying the `R` flag by itself). Change to a 301 (permanent) only when you are sure it's working OK. (301s are cached hard by the browser so can make testing problematic.)

To canonicalise the www subdomain and redirect non-www to www then add an additional directive:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect non-www to www (and HTTPS) on the same domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on the same host
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

This does assume that you don't have any other subdomains (other than www) on these domains.

Note that whilst this might at first look like two redirects (since there are two separate directives), only one redirect will result, since the first non-www to www redirect always redirects to HTTPS (so the second redirect would never occur in this case).

No need to repeat `RewriteEngine` more than once.

**UPDATE:**

> The add-ons are not in the public_html folder ...

If the Addon domains do not point to the (main domains) public_html folder, or a subdirectory of the `public_html` folder then you will need to create a separate `.htaccess` in the document root for each Addon domain, since they are completely separate entities. The above directives would then work for the Addon domains `.htaccess` file(s).

However, if the Addon domains point to subdirectories off the main domain's document root (a common default in cPanel's setup). eg. `public_html/www.example2.com/`. Then the above (single) `.htaccess` file in the `public_html` folder would still work...

UNLESS you already have additional `.htaccess` files (that also use mod_rewrite) in the Addon domain's document root directories. This is because mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default. Now, depending on your config, you could enable mod_rewrite inheritance (but stress that this would depend on your config and what other directives you already have). Otherwise, you will need to duplicate these directives in the `.htaccess` file for each Addon domain - the same as above (as if your Addon domains were in different parts of the filesystem).

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

Comment: I tried that piece of code. But the issue I'm having is that it's only working for the primary domain in the public_html . the other two addon domains are not redirecting.

Comment: The add-ons are not in the public_html folder and I cant have them there because I'm assuming the link to access it will become something like www.example1.com/www.example2.com

Comment: Also, i tried your code. It's only working for the primary ( in public_html ) it's not redirecting for the other domains.

Comment: any suggestions

Comment: "something like www.example1.com/www.example2.com" - so the Addon domains document root is a subdirectory off the main domain's document root? That itself wouldn't be a problem, unless these Addon domains also have their own `.htaccess` file that uses mod_rewrite - is that the case here? "The add-ons are not in the public_html folder" - that implies the Addon domains are elsewhere on the filesystem, but `www.example1.com/www.example2.com` implies they are in the public_html folder?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: hi. the addons are in their own folder, they aren't in the public_html, example: going onto file manager, you will see the side panel of folders, the addons have their own folder just like the public_html.

Comment: it works.......

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?Domainname\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domainname.com/$1 [R,L] in seperate .htaccess files

Comment: If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted (checkmark on the left below the voting arrows) to remove it from the unanswered question queue. You can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: Incidentally, in the directives you've just posted, the second `RewriteCond` would seem to be superfluous for the Addon domains (there is only one domain)? But also, that would not canonicalise the www subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe is normal. An `.htaccess` files applies to the folder it is in and recursively to subdirectories. Another `.htacess` can also exist in the subdirectory in which case it has precedence.

In your case you either need to split the file into three, putting the relevant third in an `.htaccess` within the right directory from where your add-on domains are served.

Or you *may* be able to put the .htaccess in the parent directory of all three domains, if there is such a directory, and the server is configured to read `.htaccess` files above `public_htm`l. In my server it does work like that but it is possible this depends on a config option.

In any case, splitting the `.htaccess` is best since it will make things easier in the future should you move servers, change servers for some of the domains, etc.